# How use cURL in pages that have redirection to GET form?

Tags: php, curl

I find a problem... I want to send a FORM in POST method to page `www.mysite.com/teste_process.php` but this page returned one redirection to page `www.mysite.com/teste.php?number=987` In this case, the number on the GET(987) is random and generated in the first page(process). I need some data that are in the second page. Using cURL I did it send the POST, but the data of second page doesn´t appear.

I used this function to send the FORM:

```js
function curl_post($url, $cookiefile, $post, $referer = "") {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
 $redirects=5000;
 $data = curl_redirect_exec($curl,$redirects);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mistake is using `curl_redirect_exec`. Instead of doing that, try replacing these two lines:

```
$redirects=5000;
$data = curl_redirect_exec($curl,$redirects);
```

With these two lines:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Doing that will follow the redirects infinitely and return the final page's data into `$data`. Also, you can use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL)` to find the final URL that cURL ended up at after following all of the redirects.